# What is the delete target of "echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" command

Tags: filesystem, memory-usage, xfs

```
sync
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

After I execute above command, available memory is significantly increased than below consumed Slab memory.

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep Slab
Slab:    6169212 kB
```

What is the delete target of "echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" command

Comment: Are you asking what *files* are being deleted when you issue this command? If so, there are no files. When you drop the caches you are flushing file buffers. These are sections of (or complete) files that are currently being used by the operating system. The point of the buffers is to reduce the number of times the same file is read from disk. This ensures the system is able to more quickly handle commonly-accessed files. Dropping these caches will force the OS to re-read the files at least once the next time the system does something requiring those libraries/resources.

Comment: Whose allocated memory will this command free? Other than Slab?

Answer (score 2):

The files in `/proc/sys/vm` can be used to tune the operation of the virtual memory (VM) subsystem of the Linux kernel. This is documented in the [kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#drop-caches):

> #### drop_caches
>
> Writing to this will cause the kernel to drop clean caches, as well as
> reclaimable slab objects like dentries and inodes. Once dropped, their
> memory becomes free.
>
> To free pagecache:
>
> ```
> echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
> ```
>
> To free reclaimable slab objects (includes dentries and inodes):
>
> ```
> echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
> ```
>
> To free slab objects and pagecache:
>
> ```
> echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
When I executed `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, Available memory is increased than Slab memory(`cat /proc/meminfo | grep Slab`).
I don't know the reason.